# Stock ticker data structure for getting top k stock prices

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am practicing some interview questions and one I came across is a stock ticker data structure problem.

Given a stream of stock prices write a data structure that supports that following operations:

```
 1. StockSticker(int k) : Initialize the size of the ticker.
 2. void addOrUpdate(String stock, double price) : Add or update a stock.
 3. List<Stock> top(int k) : Get top k stocks.
```

My idea was to use a HashMap in conjunction with the quickselection algorithm in order to get an average case O(n) complexity for the top(k) function. Would this be an efficient solution when dealing with a stream of values, or is there something better? The only other idea I have would be to use heaps, but I am not sure how to manipulate it in a way to get better than O(n).

Here is my solution:

```
    public class StockTicker {
    public class Stock{
        String sym;
        double price;

        public Stock(String s, double val){
            this.sym = s;
            this.price = val;
        }
    }

    HashMap<String,Stock> st;
    HashMap<String,Integer> ind;
    int unique;
    int max;
    Stock[] stocks;

    public StockTicker(int k){
        this.unique = 0;
        this.max = k;
        this.st  = new HashMap<String, Stock>();
        this.ind =  new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        this.stocks = new Stock[k];
    }


    public void addOrUpdate(String sym, double price){
        if(!st.containsKey(sym)){
            Stock stock = new Stock(sym,price);
            st.put(sym, stock);
            ind.put(sym, unique);
            stocks[unique++] = stock;
        }
        else{
            Stock update = st.get(sym);
            update.price = price;
        }
    }

    public List<Stock> top(int k){
        List<Stock> res = new ArrayList<Stock>();
        Stock[] temp = new Stock[max];
        for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
            temp[i] = new Stock(stocks[i].sym, stocks[i].price);
        }

        int top = quickselect(temp, 0, temp.length-1, k);

        for(int i = 0; i <= top; i++){
            res.add(temp[i]);
        }
        return res;
    }

    public int quickselect(Stock[] stocks, int left, int right, int kth){
        if(left == right){
            return left;
        }

        int split = partition(stocks, left,right);

        if(kth-1 == split){ return split;}
        else if(kth-1 > split){ return quickselect(stocks,split + 1, right, kth);}
        else { return quickselect(stocks, left , split-1, kth);}
    }

    public int partition(Stock[] stocks, int left, int right){
        int lastIndex = right;
        double pivot = stocks[lastIndex].price;
        while(left <= right){
            while( left <= right && stocks[left].price > pivot ){
                left++;
            }
            while( left <= right && stocks[right].price <= pivot){
                right--;
            }
            if(left <= right && stocks[left].price <= pivot && stocks[right].price > pivot){
                swap(stocks,left,right);
            }
        }
        swap(stocks,left,lastIndex);
        return left;
    }

    public void swap(Stock[] stocks, int x, int y){
        Stock eleX = stocks[x];
        Stock eleY = stocks[y];
        stocks[x] = eleY;
        stocks[y] = eleX;
    }

    public Stock getStock(String sym){
        return st.get(sym);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        StockTicker ticker = new StockTicker(10);

        ticker.addOrUpdate("A", 10.00);
        ticker.addOrUpdate("B", 1.00);
        ticker.addOrUpdate("C", 9.00);
        ticker.addOrUpdate("D", 2.00);
        ticker.addOrUpdate("E", 8.00);
        ticker.addOrUpdate("F", 3.00);
        ticker.addOrUpdate("G", 7.00);
        ticker.addOrUpdate("H", 4.00);
        ticker.addOrUpdate("I", 6.00);
        ticker.addOrUpdate("J", 5.00);

        List<Stock>  topStocks = ticker.top(5);

        for(Stock s: topStocks){
            System.out.print(s.sym + ": " + s.price + " ");
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: how are the top (k) stocks defined? Is the just the first k elements in the list?

Comment: It is the stocks with the highest prices. Quickselect partitions the array so that every element to the left of k would have greater or equal prices.

Comment: Also, the problem didn't specify if the stocks needs to be in any particular order, but that would make a nice follow up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do better for small `k`: you can maintain a priority queue, pop the maximum `k` times and add these elements back to the queue to answer the top `k` query in `O(k log n)` time.

In fact, you can answer each query in `O(k + log N)` time for any value of `k`, but it would require implementing a custom balanced binary search tree (with a custom tree, you just need to split it by the `k`-th position), but it can be pretty tedious to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a classic Priority Queue use case, you just need to handle the logic when new price is coming and you need to change the price of the stock which is already in the queue.

Here's a python solution from official doc:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#priority-queue-implementation-notes

Or a Java implementation of Indexed Priority Queue that is exactly what you need:
https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/IndexMinPQ.java.html